# doCallRealMethod not working for object autowired inside abstract class

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, spring-test

I am trying to write test bases for child class which has a super class. I have tried below approach but flow is not going inside enrichEvent method.

```
public abstract class StudentProcessor implements IStudentProcessor<Event> {
  @Autowired private StudentService studentService;

    public method processEvent(Event events){
     studentService.enrichEvent(event); -- void return type
     }
    }
```

Child Class Test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChildStudentProcessorTest {
 @Mock private StudentService studentService;
 @InjectMocks
  private StudentProcessor childStudentEventProcessor = new ChildStudentProcessor();
 

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
  doCallRealMethod().when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any());
 }

 @Test
 public void test_vanilaScenario() {
  Event baseModel =
      ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
  childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel);
  }
```

Comment: Putting aside syntax errors in your code, this should be working as expected. Sharing a minimal reproducible example of your issue might get you the solution faster.

Comment: Could you please share the class ChildStudentProcessor?

Comment: Why are you initializing `childStudentEventProcessor `? WIth annotation `@InjectMocks`, no need for that.

Comment: Not sure about JUnit 4 but in JUnit 5 it works as expected with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

Answer (score 1):

The following line is not correct:

```
@InjectMocks
private StudentProcessor childStudentEventProcessor = new ChildStudentProcessor();
```

You are calling the empty constructor of `ChildStudentProcessor`. You need to create a new constructor in `StudentProcessor` or in `ChildStudentProcessor` that takes `StudentService` as a parameter. Then just call:

```
@InjectMocks
private StudentProcessor studentEventProcessor;
```

So that the `studentService` that you are mocking in your test class will be passed as a parameter in the new constructor and the `doCallRealMethod` will be executed correctly.

Comment: Exactly, in general you always should prefer constructor injection over field injection, for all CDI frameworks not just for Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with Junit5 your class like the sample bellow:

```java
public abstract class StudentProcessor implements IStudentProcessor<Event> {
    // you don't need use autowired, you can use the construsctor for this
  // if you declare  private final StudentService studentService;
 // and build the constructor you can get instance too
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    public void processEvent(Event events){
        studentService.enrichEvent(events);
    }
}
```

your test class

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ChildStudentProcessorTest {
    @Mock
    private StudentService studentService;
    @InjectMocks
    private StudentProcessor childStudentEventProcessor;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        //here you define how is the implementation for your test
        childStudentEventProcessor = Mockito.mock(ChildStudentProcessor.class);
        //here you define how the studentService should do execute when recive any Event.class
        Mockito.when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any(Event.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_vanilaScenario() {
        //here you define your instance of event
        Event baseModel = ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
        //here you do call for your method for test
        childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel);
        //here you can test if the studentService is in use one time
        Mockito.verify(studentService,Mockito.times(1)).enrichEvent(baseModel);
    }
}
```

or you can use like the bellow code:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ChildStudentProcessorTest {
    @Mock
    private StudentService studentService;
    @InjectMocks
    private StudentProcessor childStudentEventProcessor;



    @Test
    public void test_vanilaScenario_ChildStudentProcessor() {
        //here you define how is the implementation for your test
        childStudentEventProcessor = Mockito.mock(ChildStudentProcessor.class);
        //here you define how the studentService should do execute when recive any Event.class
        Mockito.when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any(Event.class));

        //here you define your instance of event
        Event baseModel = ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
        //here you do call for your method for test
        childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel);
        //here you can test if the studentService is in use one time
        Mockito.verify(studentService,Mockito.times(1)).enrichEvent(baseModel);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_vanilaScenario_OtherChildStudentProcessor() {
        //here you define how is the implementation for your test
        childStudentEventProcessor = Mockito.mock(OtherChildStudentProcessor.class);
        //here you define how the studentService should do execute when recive any Event.class
        Mockito.when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any(Event.class));

        //here you define your instance of event
        Event baseModel = ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
        //here you do call for your method for test
        childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel);
        //here you can test if the studentService is in use one time
        Mockito.verify(studentService,Mockito.times(1)).enrichEvent(baseModel);
    }
}
```

if you want test with exception, you can do like the bellow code:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ChildStudentProcessorTest {
    @Mock
    private StudentService studentService;
    @InjectMocks
    private StudentProcessor childStudentEventProcessor;



    @Test
    public void test_vanilaScenario_ChildStudentProcessor() {
        //here you define how is the implementation for your test
        childStudentEventProcessor = Mockito.mock(ChildStudentProcessor.class);
        //here you define how the studentService should do execute when recive any Event.class
        Mockito.when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any(Event.class));

        //here you define your instance of event
        Event baseModel = ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
        //here you do call for your method for test
        childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel);
        //here you can test if the studentService is in use one time
        Mockito.verify(studentService,Mockito.times(1)).enrichEvent(baseModel);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_vanilaScenario_OtherChildStudentProcessor() {
        //here you define how is the implementation for your test
        childStudentEventProcessor = Mockito.mock(OtherChildStudentProcessor.class);
        //here you define how the studentService should do execute when recive any Event.class
        Mockito.when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any(Event.class));

        //here you define your instance of event
        Event baseModel = ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
        //here you do call for your method for test
        childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel);
        //here you can test if the studentService is in use one time
        Mockito.verify(studentService,Mockito.times(1)).enrichEvent(baseModel);
    }


    @Test
    public void test_vanilaScenario_ChildStudentProcessor_NullPointerException() {
        //here you define how is the implementation for your test
        childStudentEventProcessor = Mockito.mock(OtherChildStudentProcessor.class);
        //here you define how the studentService should do execute when recive any Event.class and then do
        //throw NullPointerException
        Mockito.doThrow(new NullPointerException()).when(studentService).enrichEvent(Mockito.any(Event.class));

        //here you define your instance of event
        Event baseModel = ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("events/event1.json", Event.class);
        //here you do call for your method for NullPointerException test
        Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,()->childStudentEventProcessor.processEvent(baseModel));
        //here you can test if the studentService is in use one time
        Mockito.verify(studentService,Mockito.times(1)).enrichEvent(baseModel);
    }

}
```

for more test with void methods [void test](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify)
for more test with exceptions methods [exceptions test](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/expected-exception-example/)

Comment: If you are mocking both, StudentService and StudentProcessor, then there's actually nothing left to test.

Comment: the lines of mocks can be changed for the instance... with new ChildStudentProcessor() or new OtherChildStudentProcessor(); but the structure for this is the same

Comment: If you use @InjectMocks and later reassign a new Instance, then you loose the instance with the dependencies created by Mockito.